# Columns of different types as features

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have data of different types and I want to predict the dependent variable `Y` from variables `A` `B` and `C` shown below.

```
    Y       A       B     C
0   11.3914 2.75    0     [0, 0, 10, 17, 35, 26, 0]
1   14.0348 2.50    0     [0, 0, 39, 35, 30, 5, 0]  
2   14.8416 2.75    1     [0, 0, 12, 5, 5, 2, 1]
3   13.7829 2.25    0     [0, 0, 2, 18, 14, 8, 0]   
...
```

The following attempt gives me `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` during the `fit` line.

```
X = df[['A', 'B', 'C']]
y = df['Y']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20)
tree_reg = DecisionTreeRegressor()  
tree_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
```

I assumed this was because of the array data in `C` but when I try to predict with only variables `A` and `B`:
i.e. `X = df[['A', 'B']]`

I get another error, this time in the final `predict` line: `ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 7 and input n_features is 2`

What am I doing wrong? How can I include each of these features in `X`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error in case of using  features `A and B` is due to the last line.

```py
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
```

It seems that you are using the wrong to predict. You have `fit` a model named `tree_reg` and are using another model `regressor` (maybe used for some previous data) to predict the results. In your case, `regressor` model accepts 7 feature, by you are providing only 2.

Error when using all the three features `A, B and C`

When you want to use a `list` inside a data frame, you cam make use of the `tolist()` method to convert the list to individual columns of the dataframe.

[Split column of lists into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns)